# Is Data Mining of Satellite weather image possible on a Single Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, data-mining, satellite-image

I am trying to extract data from the satellite weather image using raspberry pi and then willing on run Data mining by a single Raspberry pi. So that possible? Is that time consuming?

Comment: Which satellite weather image? From where? Mining for what? What have you tried? Where is your code? What languages do you know?

Comment: "Data mining" is an incredibly broad term. It may mean nothing more than "data processing", so you need to be much more precise. You can theoretically do everything on a Pi, given enough storage (to make up for low RAM) and enough time (to make up for the very slow CPU and the swapping necessary because of the low RAM). So yes, you can theoretically do everything (it's just not a good idea).

Comment: NOAA satellite image, mining for detecting cyclones, I have not tried yet, just analyzing the feasibility @MarkSetchell

Answer (score 0):

Data mining is of course possible. But the time consumption depends on the data that you would mine on. If you are really interested in it the you can visit [here](https://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-raspberry-pi-bitcoin-miner--cms-20353) for more information.